# how to create a file with a specific name and specific text

Tags: java

I have a file that contain tweets and its ID for example

```
1  what a nice day //1 is the ID and "what a nice day" is the tweet text 
2  how are you doing //2 is the ID and "how are you doing" is the tweet text 
.
.
. etc
```

I want to create a new file for each line and name it with the ID and inside this file I want to put the tweet text 
take the first line as an example `"1  what a nice day"`
the file name should be(`1.txt`)and inside that file `"what a nice day"`

I really dont have any idea how to do this can you please help me?

Comment: See [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The will help you I hope :

```
public static void readSplitWrite(String pathToFile){
    //To recognize how are your sentences : between 1 and 25 digit, then some spaces, and then what you want 
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,25})\\s*(.*)");
    try {
        //Read over all the lines of your file
        for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pathToFile),Charset.forName("UTF-8"))){
            //Catch the different parts of the string (group(0) is the hole sentence, group(1) is inside first (), group(2) is inside second ()
            Matcher m = patt.matcher(line);
            if(m.find()){       
                //Open a file, in UTF-8 encoding (to be able to read Arabic character, as name the ID
                Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(m.group(1)+".txt"), "UTF-8"));
                try {
                    //write the content into
                    out.write(m.group(2));
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Just the name if the file is in the folder, if not write absolute path
    String pathToFile = "Text.txt";
    readSplitWrite(pathToFile);
}
```

This code will read your file, and then create a `new File` for each line, with as name the number, and as content the sentence 
If there is any problem, tell me in comment

Edit : I commented better the code to help you

Comment: LOL actually these are the tweet's ID it must be kept so I cannt change it 
UTF-16BE didnt show any error but there is no files created

Comment: So how the ID's are ? because on your screenshot the 5 are same ^^